# how to access to the php content of a html tag in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, alert

I would like to know how to access to the php content of a html tag in jQuery. The explanation is as below:

This is my html code:

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
<b><?php $id="a"; ?></b>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$("#table_child_title").on("click", ".editlink", function(event){
var string2=$("#edittitle" ).children('b').contents();
alert(string2);
});
```

What I want is that when executing the line `alert(string2);` the alert window shows me what is between `<b>` and `</b>`. In other words, it shows exactly the message below:

```
<?php $id="a"; ?>
```

Is that possible in jQuery? If yes, what is wrong in my code and what is the right one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<?php $id="a"; ?>` and the `echo` or `print`?

Comment: @EliasNicolas : I just want that `<?php $id="a"; ?>` showed as a message in the alert window.

Comment: you cannot access the source of a php file from javascript. javascript (jquery) is client-side, it manipulates the DOM of a page which is the result of a server preprocessing (PHP).

Comment: You want to show PHP code? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You still need to echo it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Yes,that is what I want exactly. Do you have any idea about how to do that?

Comment: @EliasNicolas: Actually I like to show the PHP code as the message of the alert window. Do you have an idea about how to do that?

Comment: @revolution_forever, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible! Simply select the the `<b>` tag insite the `#edittag` div as shown below. Since php code is always executed before any jQuery script, the value of your `$id` variable will already be output.

```
alert($('#edittitle b').html());
```

However, you're not outputting it correctly in the code provided. Use `echo` to do that.

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
  <b><?php echo $id="a"; ?></b>
</div>
```

More info about `html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html/

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w9eza0y/1/)

EDIT:

To echo the result AND the pre-processed php code, replace the above with:

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
  <b<?php $id="a"; ?></b>
  <span>&lt;?php $id="a"; ?&gt;</span>
</div>
```

And in jQuery do:

```
alert($('#edittitle span').html());
```

Sadly, I don't think there is a way to do both things in one step. You have to do it separately.

[**Updated Demo (again)**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w9eza0y/3/)

Comment: what I'd like to obtain is : `<?php $id="a"; ?>` as the message of the alert window. Do you have any idea about how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I explained, the php code will exectute the `echo` before the `alert` is shown. So when your browers receives the html from the server, it will actually look like this: `<b>a</b>`, and not `<b><?php echo $id="a"; ?></b>`. If you (for whatever reason) still want to alert the php script, and not the value of `$id` - check @JayBlanchards answer.

Comment: @revolution_forever I understand what you want to do now. Check my answer and the updated demo.

Answer (score 0):

First you must echo the PHP variable:

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
<b>&lt;?php echo $id; ?&gt;</b>
</div>
```

The use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the contents:

```
var string2=$('#edittitle').children('b').text();
console.log(string2);
```

[You should not use `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: what I'd like to obtain is : `<?php $id="a"; ?>` as the message of the alert window. Do you have any idea about how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So - you don't want to echo the value of `$id`? You have to prevent your PHP code from processing, so you would need to use `&lt;?php $id="a"; ?&gt;` within your HTML. Is that what you're after? If so, my edit should work for you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I'm not sure he knows the order of execution of php and js. Even though your last comment here is correct, I don't think OP knows what he's *actually* asking.

Comment: I agree @Chris, we may be tilting at windmills - such as they are.

Comment: I don't want to  prevent your PHP code from processing. I just want to display it in the alert window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
   <b><?php echo $id="a"; ?></b>
</div>

<script>
$("#table_child_title").on("click", ".editlink", function(event){
   var string2 = $("#edittitle").children('b').html();
   alert(string2);
});
</script>
```

1. `echo` missing, that's why the variable `$id` is not shown
2. Use `.html()` / `.text()` instead of `.contents()`

If by any chance you want to print literally: `<php $id="a"; ?>`

Then you should use HTML entities to print `<>`

```
<b>&lt;php $id="a"; ?&gt;</b>
```

Comment: what I'd like to obtain is : `<?php $id="a"; ?>` as the message of the alert window. Do you have any idea about how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited my answer, there it is, but still I don't know why you want to do this :P